# Using the str join() method in the return of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm attempting to use the join method to return a string from a list of string within the return of the class `__str__()` function.

```
1    class Address:
2        def __init__(self, recipient, addressLines, country):
3            self.country = country
4            self.recipient = recipient
5            self.addressLines = addressLines
6        def __str__(self):
7            mystring = ", ".join.(self.addressLines)
8            return "Address for: " + self.recipient +", " + mystring + ", "+ self.country
9
10    addr = Address('Abe Jones', ['123 Somewhere Ln', 'Greenville, SC  29609'], 'USA')
11    print(addr)
```

When I run this, I receive an error `Bad input on line 7`. From my understanding, the `join()` method returns a string from an iterable type such as the list argument on line 10. Is this a syntax issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used an extra dot after the join function.

Edit your line 7 to:

```
mystring = ", ".join(self.addressLines)
```

Comment: Thank you @Viktor1903!!